# Find the length of a finite interval

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathcal{I}=\{[a,b)| a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b\}$

Define the length function $\ell(I)=b-a$ where $I \in \mathcal{I}$

The question asks to deduce that the length of an open interval $(a,b) = b-a$ given the above definitions

-Attempt-

since,
$(a,b)=\lim_{n \to \infty} [a - \frac{1}{n},b)$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$

Now $\ell([a-\frac{1}{n},b))=b-a+ \frac{1}{n}$ so by the continuity of $\ell$ we get $\lim_{ n \to \infty} \ell([a-\frac{1}{n},b))=\ell(\lim_{ n \to \infty}([a-\frac{1}{n},b)))=  b-a$

I am not sure of it really. Any thoughts?

EDIT: The properties of the length function $\ell$ are the usual well-known properties of the length function on real intervals.
($\ell$ is non-negative, $\ell(\phi)=0$,  monotone, countably additive and sub-additive)

Comment: The answer depends on what properties of length you are allowed to use. Using just the definition of length for half closed intervals you cannot write down the length of other types of intervals. As it stands the question does not even make sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy the length function, $\ell$ is non-negative, monotone, countably additive and subadditive and the length of the empty interval is zero.

Comment: In your EDIT you are mentioning some properties of the length function. But in the proof, you use continuity, which you didn't mention. Your last identity does not bring you any closer to the answer, as is only mentions semi-open intervals !

Answer (score 1):

Set $\delta = (b-a)/2$. If you have countable additivity, you should be able to write something like
$$
(a,b) = \big(\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty [a+\delta/2^{k+1},a+\delta/2^k)\big) \cup [a+\delta,b) ,
$$
and then use that $\delta/2^k-\delta/2^{k+1}=\delta/2^{k+1}$ and $\delta \sum_{k=0}^\infty 1/2^{k+1} = \delta \sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/2^k =  \delta$.

Answer (score 0):

If we want a *continuous continuation* of $\ell$ to open intervals, then the limit and the function must commute and 
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\ell([a+\epsilon,b))=\ell(\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}[a+\epsilon,b))=\ell((a,b))$$
while obviously

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\ell([a+\epsilon,b))=b-a.$$

---

If you don't like the shortcut

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}[a+\epsilon,b)=(a,b),$$ you can as well require the monotonicity of the continuation and use $(a,b)=\bigcup_n [a_n,b)$ where $a_n$ tends to $a^+$ and deduce $\sup_{a_n\to a^+}\ell([a_n,b))$ for a definition.